# how to add Dynamic Product Title in product page in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a product table(tbl_product) with product data with product_id, product_name,

**I want to show title in title bar the product name when I can view product details with product_id. But I failed to do that. Please help me with details.**

## Controller:::

```
    public function product_details($product_id)
{
        $data=array();
        $data['result']=$this->home_model->selectProductByProductId($product_id);
        $data['banner']=FALSE;
        $data['maincontent']=$this->load->view('single_product', $data, TRUE);

        $data['content']=$this->home_model->getContent();

        $data['title']= $content;
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

## Model:::

```
public function getContent()
{
    $this->db->select('tbl_product.product_name');
    $this->db->from('tbl_product');
    $this->db->where('product_name', $product_name);
    $product = $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

## View:::

```
 <head>
       <title> <?php echo $title; ?> </title>
 </head>
```

**I want to show title in title bar the product name when I can view product details with product_id. But I failed to do that. Please help me with details.**

Answer (score 1):

For CodeIgniter, you shoud remember,.
`$data[]` is in an array. So you can set element in `$data` in controller and retrieve  your `$data` array on you view.  You cant use

```
$data['content']=$this->home_model->getContent();
$data['title']= $content;
```

in your controller.

If you know your `product_id', then every product should different url.

use ulr helper and write this code when you want see a product

```
redirect('single_product/'.$product_id)
```

Now use [uri class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) and check your `product_id` like

```
if($this->uri->segment(2)){
   $data['title']=$this->home_model->get_title($this->uri->segment(2));
.........................
.......

}
```

and create a `get_title` method in you model

```
    public function get_title($product_id)
    {
   $query=$this->db->query("select product_name from tbl_product where product_id='$product_id'");
        $result = $query->row();
       if(isset($result)){
         $title=$result->product_name;
          return $title;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Error Notice: "Trying to get property of non-object" for the line $title=$product->product_name;

Comment: you explained great !! I got a notice error. Please check it out

Comment: make sure of your `product_name` column. this notice menas server not for found in this column

Comment: or you can use `row_array()`

Comment: It is "product_name". I just copied from db file :::: in line $title=$product->product_name;   ........... you used "$product" is there any reason ?? please

Comment: where I will use "row_array()" ?? please

Comment: Oh sorry, I go it .......... this error means `get_title()` method not found any `product_id` try your url just like http://example.com/prooduct/product_id. it should work

Comment: URL is OK. My question was for title in the head section. how can I get dynamic title data from my tbl_product ?? please

Comment: I edit my `get_title` method. it prevent this notice

Comment: I understand your question `get_title` method return product Title. please try more. it should work

Comment: Same issues with Notice. Not getting any title but showing "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Again  I edit my post. there have no $product variable its $query.. sorry

Comment: Failed Again !! uploaded your last editing model. "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: Same ERROR "Message: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: may be I cant help you. But you got lot of idea from this. try and try . you should solve your problem....... bye

Answer (score 0):

Do the following change in your view please. If you review your Controller code you are returning the array (from your Model) to the $data['content'] so your view should be as follows

```
  <head>
        <title> <?php echo $content[0]; ?> </title>
  </head>
```

Comment: It's Getting Errors: 1. "Undefined variable: product_name" and 2. "Undefined variable: content"............ Please let me know the correct one